# UIWebview Print option

Tags: javascript, objective-c, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate, airprint

I've created a container iOS app(objective c) which has only one webview. The webview is loaded with a website which is not owned by me. The website that i am accessing from webview has a print button. Tapping on it doesnt do anything. The same website when accessed via mobile browser works fine. I tried with several other websites with print button . It acts the same.
I wrote the following code for airprint. So whenever a native print button is clicked the following code is executed and it works fine.

But how can i execute this code when user clicks on print button on website ???
In other ways is there a way to detect if user clicks the print button on any website ??

```
UIPrintInfo *pi = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
pi.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
pi.jobName = webView.request.URL.absoluteString;
pi.orientation = UIPrintInfoOrientationPortrait;
pi.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;

UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
pic.printInfo = pi;
pic.showsPageRange = YES;
pic.printFormatter = webView.viewPrintFormatter;
[pic presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:^(UIPrintInteractionController *pic2, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
    // indicate done or error
}];
```

Comment: [This may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280972/capture-print-requests-from-a-uiwebview)

Comment: @nikkumang: That might be true in year 2012. But i've seen certain apps in the app store do it.I was able to print from the wrapper apps available in store.